# Задание не проходит все проверки

Tags: python, алгоритм

Решил задание. С примерами справляется верно. Но другие проверки через сайт, откуда я это задание взял, не проходит. Кто объяснит почему?

Задание:

На вход подается 2 строки. Нужно определить, можно ли превратить первую строку во вторую, заменяя одни буквы на другие, с учетом следующих правил:

- участвуют только буквы русского алфавита а-я;
- все буквы в нижнем регистре;
- за один шаг можно преобразовать все вхождения одной буквы в другую.

Входные данные
Входная информация поступает из стандартного ввода в виде одной строки. В этой строке содержатся две подстроки, разделенные пробелом. Ваше решение должно учитывать вариант, когда на вход поданы строки разной длины. Некорректные данные на вход не поступают, дополнительные проверки не требуются.

Выходные данные
В качестве ответа в стандартный вывод программа должна выводить 1 (если превратить можно) или 0 (если превратить нельзя).

**Пример 1**
Входные данные: привет прикол
Выходные данные: 1
Преобразования (выводить не нужно):

в ⇒ к (прикет)
е ⇒ о (прикот)
т ⇒ л (прикол)

**Пример 2**
Входные данные: ааббдд ддббаа
Выходные данные: 1
Преобразования (выводить не нужно):

д ⇒ я (ааббяя)
а ⇒ д (ддббяя)
я ⇒ а (ддббаа)

**Пример 3**
Входные данные: абаб ааах
Выходные данные: 0
Преобразовать нельзя, так как 'б' не сможет оказаться одновременно 'а' и 'х'.

Код Python:

```
def check():
  user_input = input()
  user_input_1 = user_input.split()
  if len(user_input_1[0]) == len(user_input_1[1]):
      for index, i in enumerate(user_input_1[0]):
          first_letter = user_input_1[0][index]
          second_letter = user_input_1[1][index]
          for index_1, k in enumerate(user_input_1[0][index:]):
              if first_letter == user_input_1[0][index_1] and 
              second_letter != user_input_1[1][index_1]:
                  return 0
      return 1
  else:
      return 0

print(check())
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код и примеры нормально

Comment: и объясните какой у вас алгоритм

Comment: Я написал сначала ответ, но потом увидел, что нужно только строку 1 в строку 2 преобразовывать, а обратно не надо, тут надо ещё подумать. )

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов python != javascript ;)

Comment: @dIm0n edited ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica в курсе. Но, думаю, логика предложенного там ответа не изменится, как и алгоритм ее воплощения. С другой стороны - я не огорчусь, если мою тревогу отклонят. )

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Не имеет значение, что по тому вопросу легко разобраться. Эти вопорсы относятся к разным меткам => не дупликат. Тревогу рекомендую отозвать т.к. много отклоненых тревог может отнять (по крайней мере на время) возможность их ставить.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica как скажете :)) Хотя это была бы первая ,кажется, отклоненная :)

Comment: А замена последовательная (заменяем первый символ, сохраняем строку, далее заменяем второй и т.д.) или сразу всё вместе (заменяем все символы одновременно). Если первое, то пример `абвгд бавгд` выдаёт `1`, хотя правильный результат `0`, потому что `абвгд -> ббвгд -> аавгд`. Или можно вводить промежуточные буквы `е`?) Но в таком случае `абвгд...я бавгд...я` не должен работать

Answer (score 1):

Я если честно не разобрался в Вашей логике, но попробовал другим методом. Это не ответ на Ваш вопрос, но может чем нибудь поможет.

```
def check():
    user_input, user_input_1 = input().split() 
    user_input, user_input_1 = list(user_input),list(user_input_1)
    if len(user_input) == len(user_input_1):
        for i in range(len(user_input)):
            if user_input[i] == user_input_1[i]:
                user_input[i] = 1
                user_input_1[i] = 1
        if len(set(user_input)) == len(set(user_input_1)):
            return 1    
        else:
            return 0 
    else: 
        return 0
print(check())
```